# Style a checkbox in datatable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables, switchery

I have a datatable from ajax source. I want to display a checkbox in one column based on its value.
If the value is `active`, checkbox should be `checked`, otherwise it remains `unchecked`. 
I am using `Switchery JS` to stylize the checkbox. It works fine in normal `HTML body`, but not inside a datatable column.

> Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sohal/gfuuazxL/4/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are doing the Switchery' *before* the dataTable is populated with data. And even if you did it after, you would still end up not having Switcherys on hidden rows, i.e on page `#2`, `#3` and so on.

So you must initialise Switchery *after* the dataTable is initialised and do the Switchery on *all* rows. You can do this in the `initComplete()` callback, and iterate over all rows by using the API `every()` method :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({
    initComplete : function() {
       this.api().rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
         this.nodes().to$().find('.js-switch').each(function(i, e) {
           var switchery = new Switchery(e, {
             color: '#26B99A'
           })
         })
       })  
    },
    ...//rest of the options
  })
})
```

forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/jpkysyp1/**